# Divide list elements into sublisits once they complete condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

My list starts with positive number and i want to divide it once the number becomes negative.But If the following numbers are negative , they should be added to same sublist. so it should look like:

````
List = [0.3 , 0.5, 0.6, -0.3 , -0.5, 0.6, 0.5 , -0.2 . -0.7 , 0.7 , 0.9 , 0.6 , -0.6]

sublist1 = [0.3 , 0.5, 0.6, -0.3 , -0.5]

sublist2 = [0.6, 0.5 , -0.2 . -0.7]

sublist3 = [0.7 , 0.9 , 0.6 , -0.6] ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can find where the sign (`np.sign`) changes from negative to positive (`diff` between sign values equals to `1 - (-1) = 2`), and create groups based on that with `cumsum` and `groupby`, then apply `list` to create lists:

```
s = pd.Series(List)
sublist1, sublist2, sublist3 = (
    s.groupby(s.apply(np.sign).diff(1).eq(2).cumsum()).apply(list))

print('sublist1 =', sublist1)
print('sublist2 =', sublist2)
print('sublist3 =', sublist3)
```

Output:

```
sublist1 = [0.3, 0.5, 0.6, -0.3, -0.5]
sublist2 = [0.6, 0.5, -0.2, -0.7]
sublist3 = [0.7, 0.9, 0.6, -0.6]
```